# Return a substring from a specified string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring, charindex

I've below query:

```
DECLARE @url varchar (max)='http://v.mercola.com/blogs/public_blog/New-Diet-Pill-Expands-1-000-Times-in-Your-Stomach-24728.aspx' 
SELECT replace(replace(RIGHT(@URL , CHARINDEX ('/' ,REVERSE(@URL))-1),'.aspx',''),'-',' ') as abc
```

Which returns below output:

**Actual output** -

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

i.e i want to eliminate the string after last occurrence of `-`.

What changes do i have to make to get the expected output..
In all i want a substring after last occurence of `/` and before last occurence of `-` as shown above.

Please help and thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR (max)='http://v.mercola.com/blogs/public_blog/New-Diet-Pill-Expands-1-000-Times-in-Your-Stomach-24728.aspx'

SELECT Reverse(LEFT(mid, Charindex('/', mid) - 1))
FROM   (SELECT Substring(Reverse(@url), Charindex('-', Reverse(@url)) + 1, Len(@url)) AS mid) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @url varchar (max)='http://v.mercola.com/blogs/public_blog/New-Diet-Pill-Expands-1-000-Times-in-Your-Stomach-24728.aspx' 

declare @suffix varchar(max)
select @suffix = RIGHT(@URL , CHARINDEX ('/' ,REVERSE(@URL))-1)

select left(@suffix, len(@suffix) - charindex('-', reverse(@suffix)))
```

Output:

```
New-Diet-Pill-Expands-1-000-Times-in-Your-Stomach
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
DECLARE @url varchar (max)='http://v.mercola.com/blogs/public_blog/New-Diet-Pill-Expands-1-000-Times-in-Your-Stomach-24728.aspx' 

DECLARE @LastSlash int = LEN(@URL) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@URL)) + 2,
        @LastMinus int = LEN(@URL) - CHARINDEX ('-', REVERSE(@URL)) + 1

SELECT SUBSTRING(@URL, @LastSlash, @LastMinus-@LastSlash)
```